# Laravel 5.4 JSON Beautify Output Formatting

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am a newbie in Laravel Development.

I want to display JSON Beautify Formatted Result on the WEB Page.

For that I wrote Below Code ....

```
Route::get('profile/{id?}', function ($id=1)
{
    $user = array('My Name', 'Laravel Developer', 'My Institution');
    return $user;
});
```

So whenever I visit **http://localhost/New/Laravel/profile** Or **http://localhost/New/Laravel/profile/?** , It showing me JSON in Simple Format instead of in a beautiful format.

What can be the problem ?

Beautiful Formatting Like Below Pic

```
http://vegibit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/laravel-collection-rendered-as-json.png
```

Comment: What do you mean by beautiful formating?

Comment: Updated Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For user details

```
Route::get('profile/{id?}', function ($id=1) {
    $user = User::find($id);
    return response()->json($user);
});
```

For your array

```
Route::get('profile/{id?}', function ($id=1) {
    $user = array(
        'name' => 'My Name', 
        'title' => 'Laravel Developer', 
        'other' => 'My Institution'
    );

    return response()->json($user);
});
```

Comment: Look at this Video Bro for just 5 sec
https://youtu.be/fsC50ncQFbA?list=PL9fcHFJHtFaai-ch9icvQOU69XzsKJJtD&t=442

Comment: @JoneDoe I did it. He did the same using controllers.

Comment: Appreciate your Efforts Bro. Accepting your answer.